# Read XML from Azure Blob storage in Automation PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell

Trying to figure out how to read an XML file from public blob storage.

When I have the XML in my powershell script, I was able to reference it like so:

```
[xml]$xml = @"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PublicSubnets>
<Subnet>1.2.3.0/24</Subnet>
<Subnet>2.3.4.0/24</Subnet>
<Subnet>192.168.1.0/24</Subnet>
<Subnet>10.0.0.0/8</Subnet>
</PublicSubnets>
"@

foreach ($subnet in $xml.PublicSubnets.Subnet)
{
$subnet
}
```

This would print the four subnets.

I'm trying to get that XML into a separate XML document, that's stored in public blob storage. 
Example: https://teststorage.blob.core.windows.net/automation/Subnet.xml

So basically looking for the same functionality I had with the XML included in the script, but looking for the XML to be hosted externally (I removed the first and last line of the XML - "[xml]$xml = @"" and ""@"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a SAS token for the blob and grab the URI and SAS token and put them into the variables $XmlBlobUrl (The Uri of the XML Blob) and $SASToken (Query string of the SAS token)

```
$XmlBlobUrl = "https://BlobStorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/subnets.xml"
$SASToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$Url = $XmlBlobUrl + $SASToken
$Subnets = @()

[xml]$xml = Invoke-WebRequest $Url | Select-Object -Expand Content

foreach ($subnet in $xml.PublicSubnets.Subnet) {
    $Subnets += $Subnet
}

$Subnets
```

Comment: Security Tip: I have to however stress that putting a SAS token into a script is not a secure practise and it would be better to create a function from this code and then pass the SASToken to the function as a parameter. Or when using the script, generate a SAS token with a short lifespan or revoke the token once the script has been used. Generate a new token each time you need to access the XML.

Comment: Hi - The blob is public - there's nothing secret in it, so I would like to just look to the document at https://teststorage.blob.core.windows.net/automation/Subnet.xml without having to use blobs, etc.

Comment: @S.Space In that case you can remove the first two variables $XmlblobURL and $SasToken. Change the $Url variable to the url of the xml file.

Comment: I run that and nothing shows :(.  If I run Invoke-WebRequest $URL | Select-Object -Expand Content then it shows the XML, but the foreach loop doesn't work

Comment: Nevermind - my mistake.  Worked great.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: @S.Space no problem. Glad to help.

Comment: @S.Space, if the answer works, you should mark it as answer.

Comment: I did try, but it says that I have less than 15 reputation so I can't